# How to get local (regional) date format in linux?

Tags: c, linux, bash, date

is it possible (if so, how?) to get local (regional) date format? Ideally in cross-platform way, otherwise at least Linux for start would be enough.

What am I talking about: For example this line when executed in terminal returns date (and time) formatted in local (regional) manner:

```
date +"%c"
```

What I would like to have instead of the numbers is the form in which this is displayed, for example if I set my regional setting to Lithuanian ones I get:

```
2016 m. birželio 27 d. 19:06:11
```

So I would like to get this instead of the above:

```
YYYY MM DD
```

If I set regional settings to US ones:

```
Mon 27 Jun 2016 07:09:24 PM EEST
```

In this case instead of the above I would like to get:

```
DD MM YYYY
```

Meaning - not the actual numbers, but how local(regional) date is formatted.

I later want to use this information for input/output operations facing user

Comment: You might want to read more about [`strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime) and its formats. Like the `"%c"`  format.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg all of those options return one or another result, but none of them delivers the formatting itself. Maybe I'm not clear in my post/question in regard that I want the letters, not the numbers. For example maybe there is a system database of sorts which tells to strftime what formatting to use, when %c is called. I want that information - what formatting is used.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that you don't *need* to know what the actual format. The [`strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime) also accepts the `"%c"` format, giving you the locale (region) dependent date and time output you seem to want. Otherwise you can always get the source for the `date` program and look at what it does.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks. I think I got it. Will later post answer for future reference.

Comment: "none of them delivers the formatting itself. " is a problem as the local date/time format is dynamic.  It can change over the life of the program.  So getting the format, for later use, may not provide the present data/time format.

Comment: I know this is late, but I feel it's well worth pointing out that both @Joachim and @chux rather miss the point. At least, the question is _exactly_ what I wanted an answer to, and the transitory nature is irrelevant. in my case, Chrome says it uses the OS locale for HTML `<input type=date />`, and I needed to verify exactly what format it should therefore be using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Joachims hint is correct, here a solution for your original question.
Just enter in bash:

```
locale -k LC_TIME | grep ^d_fmt | cut -d= -f2
```

If you need the time format instead of the date format, use `t_fmt` instead of `d_fmt`, and for the combined date/time format use `d_t_fmt`

Comment: Thank you @Matthias, I've found the file, based on Joachims hint, but was unable to decode the binary format. Thank you very much!

Comment: Even simpler bash command that gives the same output:

`locale d_fmt`